# How can I store an array of complex numbers?

Tags: c++, complex-numbers, stdcomplex

I want to write code that takes a sequence of complex numbers and searches for a number in it. But I don't know how to write a function to form the sequence. This is what I've tried so far:

```
class complex { 
private:
    int real;
    int image; 
    int n;
    int *a;
    
public:
    complex(float l, float k) : real(l), image(k) {}
        
    float set(float l, float k)
    {
        cout << "enter size of array: ";
        cin >> n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << "enter real part: ";
            cin >> l;
            cout << "enter image part: ";
            cin >> k;
            *(a+i) = complex(l, k);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Why not use `std::complex` and `std::vector`?

Comment: What is `a` doing here? It's never initialized, but you go ahead and use it, which is *bad*. In C++ try and avoid pointers whenever practical as they create way more trouble than most are prepared to deal with.

Comment: PSA: If you are using pointers, `a[i]` is *way* easier to understand than `*(a+i)`.

Comment: See [std::complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) and [std::literals::complex_literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i)

Comment: The code doesn't allocate any memory to store the objects. Do yourself a favor and follow the previous suggestions: use `std::vector`.

Comment: Your complex type shouldn't be the one creating and storing the array of complex types. That doesn't make any sense.  A complex number just has a real and imaginary component.

Comment: You are placing to much stuff in single function. Separate "complex" (or use `std::complex`) from array (use std::vector) and from io code (create separate function for reading single complex number and then write function which reads this ti an array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you arent allowed to use the library (which is stupid), what I would suggest is creating a struct to save the data

```
struct complexNum {             
  int real;        
  int imaginary;   
};
```

The other problem is that `a` is undefined as is and why not just use `a[i]`. Also instead why not create a typical array? You also dont need arguments or a return type for your function.

Something like:

```
class complex{  
    private:
        struct complexNum {             
            int real;        
            int imaginary;   
        };
        int n;
        complexNum* a;
    
    public:        
        void set()
        {
            cout<<"enter size of array: ";
            cin>>n;
            a = new complexNum[n];
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                complexNum num;
                cout<<"enter real part: ";
                cin>>num.real;
                cout<<"enter image part: ";
                cin>>num.imaginary;
                a[i]=num;
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: I would recommend using the standard libarary. It already has support for complex numbers, best of all that code has already been tested.

Comment: Sorry to nag, but don't use useless `new` there is no need to make `std::complex<int> a` a pointer. Try to avoid new/delete in C++ as much as you can and if you must have some sort of dynamic memory allocation the either use a container (like std::vector<T>) or std::make_unique<T>/std::unique_ptr<T>

Comment: Sorry could you edit the code so I can see how it *should* be?

Comment: Online demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/pJNKv3F4q

Comment: You're welcome. If you're interested in learning more C++. Good sources to learn cpp from are : A [recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or have a go at https://www.learncpp.com/ (that's pretty decent, and pretty up-to-date).
For C++ reference material use : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). And after you learned the C++ basics from those sources, look at the [C++ coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) regularely to keep up-to-date with the latest guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use complex numbers from the standard library and make a vector (array) from them. With std::complex_literals you can even postfix floating point numbers with an `i` to do calculations with them.
For your use case you can also use `std::complex<int>` (I missed that)

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::complex_literals;
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> values{ {1.0,1.0}, {2.0,2.0}, {3.0,3.0} };

    for (const auto value : values)
    {
        std::cout << 3.0i * value << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not have permission to use the library

Comment: Please [note](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) though, that *"The behavior [of `std::complex<T>`] is unspecified (and may fail to compile) if T is not a cv-unqualified standard (until C++23) floating-point type"*.

Comment: Why not? Are you learning C++? Or is it a datastructures class.

Comment: @Bob__ Which is kind of translates to only use `int, float, double,...` and do not use `const` or `volatile` for T right?

Comment: Well, not really, it kinda say that you *can* [use](https://godbolt.org/z/fYedcGs3Y) `int`, but with *unspecified* results (although [predictable](https://godbolt.org/z/jo7dWaqK1), IMHO).